# How to convert javascript array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `const arr = ['boy', '2', 'girl', '25', 'dog', '6']` and I want to convert it to and object so it will be come `newCreatedObject = {'boy': '2', 'girl': '25', 'dog': '6'}`.

Here is what i have tried:

```
const newCreatedObject = arr.reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) => {
      return {...acc, [cur]: arr[i + 1]};
    }, {})
```

This is what I get `{'6': undefined, '25': 'dog', '2': 'girl', 'boy': '2', 'girl': '25', 'dog': '6'}`

the result I want is coming at the later of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take only each second element for the result.

```js
const
    array = ['boy', '2', 'girl', '25', 'dog', '6'],
    object = array.reduce(
        (acc, cur, i, arr) => i % 2
            ? { ...acc, [arr[i - 1]]: cur }
            : acc,
        {}
    );

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works I never thought of it this way. thanks once again : )